# How to open browser always in new window

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

I am using this code to open a URL in the browser.

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

but it always open in the same window.

Is it possible to force to open a new window? (something similar to target="_blank" in the web)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following code:

```
   Intent myIntent  = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    myIntent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString ("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    myIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

The above code should create new tab every time you click on the url. If this doesn't work, you can try the below code:

```
Intent myIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                                           myIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID,mContext.getPackageName());                    myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);             
myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: These are just snippets copied from Stackoverflow questions which had the opposite problem. I cannot award the answer.
I am looking for an informed answer which provides a clear explanation of what actually determines a URL to be opened in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT) to force (compatible) browsers to open the link in a new tab.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```